# Passing variable from assembler to C

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        __asm__ (
                "result:    \n\t"
                ".long 0    \n\t" 
                "rdtsc      \n\t"
                "movl %eax, %ecx\n\t"
                "rdtsc      \n\t"
                "subl %ecx, %eax\n\t"
                "movl %eax, result\n\t"
        );

        extern int result;
        printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

I would like to pass some data from assembler to `main` via the `result` variable. Is this possible? My assembler code causes a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I am using Ubuntu 15.10 x86_64, gcc 5.2.1.

Comment: GCC has [Extended ASM](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for this, allowing you to refer to an output variable in that `__asm__` fragment.

Comment: To add to that: the code as it stands allocates space for `result` in the program's code segment, and `.long 0` produces two `add    %al,(%rax)` instructions.

Comment: If you want to read the clock, why not just use `unsigned long long a = __builtin_ia32_rdtsc()`?  Then you don't need to write any asm.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach could be:

```
int main (void)
{
    unsigned before, after;

    __asm__
    (
        "rdtsc\n\t"
        "movl %%eax, %0\n\t"
        "rdtsc\n\t"
        : "=rm" (before), "=a" (after)
        : /* no inputs */
        : "edx"
    );

    /* TODO: check for after < before in case you were unlucky
     * to hit a wraparound */
    printf("%u\n", after - before);
    return 0;
}
```